# Website don't open with https

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtual, host

I have a problem about SSL Certificate on Apache2 virtual host. I have configured my virtual host file correctly so when im trying to reach my website with https://mywebsite.com its ok! But when im trying to reach my website like mywebsite.com its going to default page of hosting ( var/www/html ) not  var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html.

I just wanna make who write mywebsite.com always open with https.
If i put on .htaccess file on my default hosting page other websites which directed to host ip will be effected this situation.

Server Spec: Ubuntu 14.04 / Apache2
mywebsite.com.conf

```
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
ServerAdmin hostmaster@mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/public.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/intermediate.cer
```

Comment: You need to check if apache is even finding/parsing your .conf file, and then you have to check what OTHER site definitions are in the other .conf files that may be overriding what you have above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, i created a new conf file for non-ssl from default conf and set destination of folder to same then i added .htaccess to force https.